# How to cover catch block in test class for schedulable class

Tags: apex

```
global void execute(Database.BatchableContext batchableContext, List<Account> accountList) {

        try {
            new AccountHandler().processAccountRecords(accountList);

        } catch(Exception ex){
            System.debug(ex.getStackTraceString());}

    }
```

Comment: you need to prepare a dataset which might create an error and enter into that block

Comment: check in your AccountHandler where it will throw error.. create test data where it will throw error.. it will cover your catch part.

Answer (score 1):

This is an [anti-pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-pattern):

```
try {
    // Do something
} catch(Exception ex) {
    // Log or just ignore
}
```

If it includes logging, it might be helpful during development. But in production it amounts to a "silent failure" where there is no immediate evidence that something has gone wrong. Also, the transaction will not be rolled-back, meaning that the work can be left half done. (For an extreme case imagine one bank account has been debited but an exception is thrown before another has been credited: money "disappears".) No-one may realise there is a problem, and when they do it is extra hard to diagnose.

Generally best to not catch these exceptions unless you have a good strategy on what to do about them. But if you do catch them and cannot *recover* the situation, you should re-throw like this:

```
try {
    // Do something
} catch(Exception ex) {
    System.debug(ex.getStackTraceString());
    throw ex;
}
```

so that the error is reported (in this case) in the Apex Job Queue and the transaction is correctly rolled-back.